# Absolute session timeout with Lift / Jetty

Tags: jetty, lift, session-timeout

What is a good way to implement an absolute session timeout in a Lift application running under Jetty?

I already have an idle timeout, but I want sessions to eventually time out even if the user is never idle.

Comment: Is there something specific you want to accomplish or is there a certain set of conditions that you are looking to have the session time out under? Or, do you really just want the user to be logged after XXX minutes - no matter what the user is in the middle of doing?

Comment: Yes, terminate the session X minutes after it was created, regardless of what the user is doing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You should be aware of the effects of destroying a session while active components are running (like comet-actors, ajax-requests, ...). But you may be able to create a client-side script which redirects to the start/warning-page of your side, once it detects the session is invalid. `LiftRules.noCometSessionCmd` and `LiftRules.noAjaxSessionCmd` are your friend for this.

Now: You want to leverage the mechanisms that lift's `SessionMaster.sessionCheckFuncs` is providing you. Every 10 seconds it runs this method and provides you all current valid sessions. Never! store a reference to the session itself. Thats why lift provides you with a unique-identifier, which we can leverage. Solution is based on David Pollack's code to kill sessions on high-traffic spikes, which you can find here: https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Sessions

In your Boot.scala add:

```scala
// append forced session timeout to list of checker-funcs
SessionMaster.sessionCheckFuncs = SessionMaster.sessionCheckFuncs 
  ::: List(ForcedSessionTimeout)
```

And then in your lib package:

```scala
import net.liftweb.common._
import net.liftweb.http.SessionInfo
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._

object ForcedSessionTimeout extends 
   Function2[Map[String, SessionInfo], SessionInfo => Unit, Unit] 
   with Loggable {

  @volatile var sessionTimeoutMillis: Long = 30 * 60 * 1000 // 30 minutes

  private var firstSeen: Map[String, Long] = Map.empty

  def apply(sessions: Map[String, SessionInfo], destroyer: SessionInfo => Unit): Unit = {
    logger.info("Session check!")
    val timeoutThreshold = millis - sessionTimeoutMillis

    val newFirstSeen: Map[String, Long] = sessions.map {
      case (name, si @ SessionInfo(session, agent, _, cnt, lastAccess)) =>
        firstSeen.get(name) match {
          case Some(firstTimeSeen) =>
            if (firstTimeSeen < timeoutThreshold) {
              logger.info(s" Session $name expired after forced session timeout")
              destroyer(si)
            }
            name -> firstTimeSeen

          case None =>
            // add to first seen list
            name -> millis
        }
    }
    // update first seen map, this prevents a leak if we added a session to the map
    // but lift already expired the session for another reason
    this.firstSeen = newFirstSeen
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd build what you want from scratch using Lifts feautures. Some idea like the following:

use a `SessionVar` with a TimeoutStorage inside (see below)

define this storage as something like this:

```
class TimeoutStorage[T] {
    private var inner: Option[(T, Long)] = None // the last argument is when the data was set
    def set {} // set the value. If you want to clear the memory as fast as possible, schedule an erase. Otherwise it would be erased with the `SessionVar` anyway.
    def get{} // check if it has expired
}
```

If you want a visual timeout for the user -- add an actor like @jcern said. Or maybe just `net.liftweb.util.Schedule` a small function that will send a JS to the browser (this must be possible, altrough one should take care than an appropriate `net.liftweb.http.S` is in scope).